# Caching threads to avoid initialization

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a large optimization problem that I am solving using a BFGS optimizer that I wrote. The optimizer makes many calls to the objective function, and that takes some time. I would like to speed this up. Now inside the objective function, I could make use of parallelism, because the objective function is the sum of something like 100 independent calculations.

The problem however is that if I add parallelism inside the objective function, the program will have to construct destroy every thread for every call in the optimizer.

Is there a way to initialize once the multi threading mechanism?

Schematically it looks like this:

```
public class Optimizer
{
    public static double[] Minimize(Func<double[],double> objective, double[] guess)
    {
        while(condition) 
        {
            update_guess(guess);
            var value = objective(guess);
        }
        return guess;
    }
}

public class Problem
{
    public void Solve()
    {
        var guess = new double[50];
        Func<double[],double> objective = x => 
        {
            // this is not the best way because it will be called many times
            return x.AsParallel().Select(x => ExpensiveStuff(x)).Sum()
        }

        var results = Optimizer.Minimize(objective, guess);
    }
}
```

Comment: Create a List of computations (to be managed as a stack). Create one secondary thread per core. On each step, in a "while" loop, pop one computation from the stack and execute it (while loop stops if no more computation is available).

Comment: If you use `Parallel.For` it will take care of all those details.

Comment: Can you please code up both solutions you're proposing and then demonstrate to us that there is an issue with "parallelism inside the objective function"? Then we can help you to write it correctly. Right now you're expecting us to do too much to get a possible solution - especially given that we can't compare our solution to the one you think might run poorly.

Comment: There are too many possible answers. That said, the thread pool is specifically designed for this type of scenario. Threads will be added as necessary, and they will remain available for further processing. The thread pool could in fact be described as a "thread cache", just as you describe here. Use it directly via `ThreadPool`, or use something like the `Parallel` class or `Task.Run()` to initiate operations using thread pool threads.